# Apache Nifi 1.7 Replace Text Processor for Timestamp manipulation

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use the Apache Nifi 'Replace Text' Processor to extract the year, month and day values from a timestamp field:

```
Search value: "happened":"([^"]+)"
Replacement Value: "happened":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')}","year":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy", '+00:00')}","month":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("MM", '+00:00')}","day":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("dd", '+00:00')}"
```

I am trying to convert:

```
"happened":"2018-03-28T10:52:44.35+02:00"
```

to

```
"happened":"2018-03-28 08:52:44.035","year":"2018","month":"03","day":"28"
```

This works well in Apache Nifi 1.4.

However, in Nifi 1.7, I get:

```
"happened":"2018-03-28 08:52:44.035","year":"","month":"","day":""
```

Appreciate thoughts on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Óscar Andreu  is correct - `'$1'` is evaluated only once inside the expression scope i.e - `${'$1'}`

But I couldn't find a way to extract to a temporary variable and reuse it.

I however observed that `$1` can be used as it is multiple times. This for example:

`happened = "happened":${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')},"year":"$1","month":"$1",day:"$1"`

outputs:

`"happened":"2018-03-28 08:52:44.035", "year":"2018-03-28T10:52:44.35+02:00", "month":"2018-03-28T10:52:44.35+02:00", "day":"2018-03-28T10:52:44.35+02:00"`

After which I used three more instance of ReplaceText processors one each for year, month and day respectively. Seems a bit obtuse, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `$1` can be evaluated only once, if you change the order of the replacement like this:

```
"happened":,"year":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy", '+00:00')}","month":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("MM", '+00:00')}","day":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("dd", '+00:00')}""${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')}","year":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy", '+00:00')}","month":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("MM", '+00:00')}","day":"${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("dd", '+00:00')}"
```

you get this:

```
"happened":,"year":"2018","month":"","day":"""","year":"","month":"","day":""
```

Now the point is how to solve the issue, I don't know which are your specific requirements, but for me the easiest way is:
 - Extract the date to an attribute.
 - With this attribute construct the new value you need like in the expressions bellow.

```
happenedData = ${'$1':toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')}

happened = "happened":"${happenedData}","year":"${happenedData:format("yyyy", '+00:00')}","month":"${happenedData:format("MM", '+00:00')}","day":"${happenedData:format("dd", '+00:00')}"
```